# Team Foundation Server 2013 Error TF400129: Verifying SQL connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, failed-installation

I'm trying to install TFS2013 (en_visual_studio_team_foundation_server_2013_with_update_4_x86_x64) on my machine (windows 8.1 x64)

I had a existing SQL instance installed and tried to use that one during my TFS installation but I kept on getting error messages about TFS not being able to connect to my SQL instance.

I started googling te error message and found guides about how you needed to config the SQL to be put on port 1433, add Firewall Rules,.. I tried literally *everything*, nothing worked.

So I decided to completely remove my SQL instance and install the SQL SERVER 2012 Express edition that comes with the TFS installer. The SQL installation completes successfully, but when configuring TFS again, the same error popped up.

So I went another step further and removed the SQL Server instance again and downloaded the SQL SERVER 2014 Express edition. Yet, same problem.

I've been looking around the web for the error but can't seem to find anything useful. Note that using a database on the SQL SERVER instance from code or connecting using the SQL Management Studio works like charm!

I started inspecting the full blown error log TFS provided me with and found this:

> TF400129: TF400129: Error from readiness check: Verifying SQL
>   connection [Info   @18:58:47.025] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying SQL connection
>   |+-+-+-+-+- [Info   @18:58:47.025] Starting Node: VSQLCONNECT [Info
>   @18:58:47.025] NodePath :
>   VINPUTS/Progress/Conditional/VSQLNOTLOCALDB/VSQLISRUNNING/VSQLCONNECT
>   **> [Error  @18:58:47.025] System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation
>   resulted in an overflow.**    at
>   SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO* , SNI_ConnWrapper** )
>   at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncEx(ConsumerInfo consumerInfo,
>   String constring, IntPtr& pConn, Byte[] spnBuffer, Byte[]
>   instanceName, Boolean fOverrideCache, Boolean fSync, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNIHandle..ctor(ConsumerInfo myInfo, String
>   serverName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int32
>   timeout, Byte[]& instanceName, Boolean flushCache, Boolean fSync,
>   Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.CreatePhysicalSNIHandle(String
>   serverName, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Byte[]&
>   instanceName, Byte[] spnBuffer, Boolean flushCache, Boolean async,
>   Boolean fParallel)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
>   ...

For completeness, this is the error screen I can't pass:
[image: TFS_2013_TF400129_Error_Message]

I'm really at a dead end here. Ive been trying to get this fixed for days now and I come here as my last resort. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network? I would suggest that SQL ports are being blocked.

Comment: Can you connect to SQL Server from the SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Hello, as I noted in my problem description, I performed every possible configuration of my firewall, adding exceptions for both sqlservr.exe, 1433 TCP, UPD, even completely disabling the firewall and THEN try again: not working. I am doing this on my own computer so I'm not on a corporate network. Also, as noted in my description, connection from code and SQL Management studio works just fine..

Comment: Did you enter the correct instance name? Likely localhost\sqlexpress if you ever had express installed.